# is there a way to get specific javascript used for a section in html website from a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, menu, toggle

i have an html website where in the mobile view,the menu is set as toggle menu using javascript, the code is inside a javascript file: [file](https://demo.thebrandchimp.com/jewelit/assets/assets/js/vendors/plugins.min.js)

the menu is working fine, but in some pages while using this file, some of my sliders are getting affected so i had to remove this file but then the toggle menu wont appear instead the menu for desktop appears [example](https://demo.thebrandchimp.com/jewelit/homecontroller/types/2)

is there a way to separate toggle menu code from this javascript file, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your samples are a pain to read through especially your JS file. So, that's that.

Now, I have no idea why your have that many lines of code just to toggle a menu. What you need are some CSS and a little JavaScript to toggle classes. That's it, if it were me.

So, here's a little something from my CodePen to help illustrate my point. You can just modify the files and use it for the menu

```js
$('a.drop').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next().toggleClass('active');
});

$('.toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('nav > .menu').toggle();
  $(this).html(($(this).html() == 'x' ? '&#x2630;' : 'x'));
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8);
}
h5 {padding: 8px;}
nav > .menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%; left: 0; right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.8)
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 12px;
}
.toggle {display: block}
a {text-decoration: none;}
li a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.1);
}
.links {white-space: nowrap;}
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding: 8px 12px;
}
a.drop {
  padding-right: 24px;
}
a.drop:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 8px;
  transform: translateY(-75%) rotate(45deg);
  width: 5px; height: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #444;
  border-color: transparent #444 #444 transparent;
}
.menu .menu, ul.menu .list {
  display: none;
}
.menu .menu.active, ul.menu .list.active, .menu.active > .list {
  display: block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .toggle {display: none}
  nav > .menu {
    width: 90%;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  nav > ul > li > a {
    padding: 32px!important;
  }
  li:hover > .list, li:hover > .menu {
    border-top: 2px solid #333;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%; left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  li:hover .menu > .list {
    display: inline-block;
  }
  li:hover .menu a {
    max-width: 120px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/60" alt=""></a>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="drop">Menu 1</a>
      <ul class="list">
        <li><a href="#">Sub Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sub Link 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="drop">Menu 2</a>
      <div class="menu">
        <ul class="list">
          <li><h5>Sub Header 1</h5></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>  
        <ul class="list">
          <li><h5>Sub Header 2</h5></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sub Link 4</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="links">F T G I S &nbsp;</div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle">&#x2630;</a>
</nav>
```